# Connect-PnPOnline: Unsupported user type 'unknown'

Tags: powershell, 2016, error, pnp-powershell

I have installed `SharePointPnPPowershell` on my dev machine which is running SP 2016.

I tried to connected to my local sharepoint site using:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $cred
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Connect-PnPOnline : Unsupported User Type 'Unknown'. Please see https://aka.ms/msal-net-up. 
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Connect-PnPOnline $url
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], MsalClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline
```

`$cred` is OK (UserName myUserName)

This script worked some weeks ago. We use SSO.

Any Idea?

I tried the solution below:
I don't get an error, but the return value is $null:

```
$snPnPConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential
$snPnPConn -eq $null
True
```

But get $null as return value

Answer (score 1):

Use below script to connects to on-premises SharePoint 2013, 2016 or 2019 site with the current user's on-premises Windows credential (e.g. domain\user).

- Some of PnP command will not work in on premises.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://portal.contoso.com" -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential
```

Refer the this docs for more details

- [Connect PnP Online](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#example-11)

Comment: I tried the solution below: I don't get an error, but the return value is $null:

```$snPnPConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential
$snPnPConn -eq $null
True
```
But get $null as return value

Comment: It should work as per documentation.

Comment: After connecting directly call , cmdlet i.e. Get-PnPWeb.

Comment: Please use Connect-PnPOnline instead of $snPnPConn =Connect-PnPOnline. I doubt if Connect-PnPOnline will return any thing.

Comment: Why and when changed it. It was a working script.
Now I have the additional switch ReturnConnection, but the commands doesn't work.
O.K. I don't can edit this comment. How can I answer? After Return it will be send.

Comment: Why and when changed it. It was a working script.
Now I have the additional switch ReturnConnection, but the commands doesn't work.
O.K. I don't can edit this comment. How can I answer? After Return it will be send.
```
ConnectionType                         : O365
InitializationType                     : Unknown
...
```
What is the InitializationType?
```
Get-PnpList
Get-PnpList : Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (403) Unzulässig.
```

Answer (score 0):

For PS 5 use modules SharePointPnPPowerShell2013, SharePointPnPPowerShell2016

then you can connect :

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $cred
```

Form PS 7 use module PnP.PowerShell:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://portal.contoso.com" -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with my SP 2019. I tried the following:

1. `Install-Module -Name "PnP.PowerShell"`
2. `Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShell2019`
3. closed powershell command window and opened a new one
4. ran: `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "http://[siteUrl]" -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Got error: `Connect-PnPOnline : Unsupported User Type 'Unknown'. Please see https://aka.ms/msal-net-up.`

5. ran the following: `Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2019`
6. exectuted this again: `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "http://[siteUrl]" -Credential (Get-Credential)`

and then everything worked just fine:

```
Url                                   CompatibilityLevel
---                                   ------------------
http://wsam                            15
```

I hope this helps someone else.